# what's better for performance? several pictures with their size adjust to their spaces, or just one?

Tags: css, performance, html

I have a webpage in which i use a picture as a background on several sections. It's a big one (around 1200x1200). But, every place where i put it have several size, for example, the footer has a size around 1000x1000, one section in the middle of the webpage has a dimension of 200x300 and the header around 1100x1100.

So, my question is: what's better for perfomance? Should i create several pictures with their corresponding dimension's the closer possible to their corresponding places o just have one a let the hard work to the browser?

Answer (score 1):

One large image is always better.
If there are many small images the browser has to make that many requests. Which can create a lot of network overhead. So you can use one big image that contains all the images & you can show a part of it using [Image Sprites](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp). And as `@Sheepy` suggested you can optimize images using [Tinypng.com](http://tinypng.com).

Answer (score 0):

If you make a several images, it will cause a huge delay in your page loading speed so the best option is to let the browser do it, because it will just rework previously loaded image.

But remember, it will work only for images that are proportional to your main image. Mind that if you will resize 1200x1200 square image into 200x300 rectangle, it's going to look weird.

Another thing is what kind of pictures do you use. If it's just a gradient or background in a one colour, it doesn't matter - let the browser do the job. But if it is a picture of something, like a tree or a human, resizing it will give you a weird result.

Comment: Who gave that negative to this answer??

Comment: Seems like someone dislikes me :D

Comment: I didnt. Really appreciate tour answer, thank you very much!

Comment: It could be that the downvoter found your answer not nuanced enough. You stated "it will cause a huge delay", but that's not always the case. If a website loads ten 300x300 images, those may load just as quickly as one single 1200x1200 image!

Answer (score 0):

When the images are small and there are many of them, like product images, it is better to pre-scale the images and deliver the proper resolution.
The reason is simple: it is slow to download and render many full size product images in a product list, when you only need small thumbnails.

But your image is relatively big and close - one images at 1200, 1100, and 1000 square, plus a small one.
In this case I think it is better to use one big image and let browser reuse that cache, perhaps supported by an individual 200x300.

Although the speed of decompressing an image is sometimes a factor, it is often dwarfed by transfer time and page faults.

But it helps, too. Most rendering time is spent on decompressing an image. Scaling is relatively fast.
A shared image may be able to reuse the same uncompressed data ("raw image").
The details is pretty complicated, and out of your control as usual, but it won't hurt if you try.
Even if it can't save render time, at least you reduce the chance of filling up the memory cache.

Keep in mind that different browsers may scale the image [differently](http://entropymine.com/resamplescope/notes/browsers/),
and you have [few control](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/image-rendering) over it.
If the result is unacceptable you don't have much choice left, but at least you tried.

> Whether you end up using one or many image, try to use [mozjpeg](https://github.com/mozilla/mozjpeg) to optimise it/them.  You will get much smaller size for the same quality (and vice versa) than from Photoshop or other common tools.

Comment: Thank you very much for the advise and webpages suggested! I used another one for called: http://resizeimage.net/ to optimize it, now I will use this one that you recommend and compare them.

Comment: @user4212648 mozjpeg is a very specialised tool.  It does only one thing but do it well.  It'll cost you an additional step, but at your image size I feel that it will be worth the time to [setup](https://github.com/Sheep-y/tools/tree/master/mozjpeg).